# Inline threaded dispatch with memcpy

Tags: c, inline, interpreter, mmap, memcpy

I'm testing out an interpreter dispatch technique referred to as [inline threading](https://blog.mozilla.org/dmandelin/2008/08/27/inline-threading-tracemonkey-etc/) and I can't seem to branch into executable memory without segfaulting.  I am using the [labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) extension of GCC to determine the starts and ends of each opcode span.

**test.c:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  int i = 0;

  if (argc > 0x10) {
    // prevent optimization 
    inc_start: i++; inc_end:;
    ret_start: goto end; ret_end:;
  }

  void* m = mmap(
    0,  
    getpagesize(),
    PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
    MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
    -1, 
    0); 

  if (!m) {
    return -1; 
  }

  {
    char* x = m;
    memcpy(x, &&inc_start, &&inc_end - &&inc_start); x += &&inc_end - &&inc_start;
    memcpy(x, &&inc_start, &&inc_end - &&inc_start); x += &&inc_end - &&inc_start;
    memcpy(x, &&ret_start, &&ret_end - &&ret_start); x += &&ret_end - &&ret_start;
  }

  goto *m; 

  end:
  return i;
}
```

**Compile and run with:**

```
gcc test.c -O0 && ./a.out; echo $?
```

I am expecting main to return 2, but instead :

```
Segmentation fault
139
```

I'm compiling with gcc 4.7.2 on a 64-bit linux machine and am confident nothing is being optimized away.  Any tips on how to get this working?

Comment: Youir code is not standard C and invokes undefined behaviour. What is your question?

Comment: Did you refer to the labels as values link?  Yes it's not standard but the extension is supported by most C compilers.  How did the author of this whitepaper get inline threaded dispatch working? http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/publications/papers/2003-2/sable-paper-2003-2.pdf  Please refer to figure 2.

Comment: I will not, because that is a wrong approach and not allowed for good reasons. I'm not here to tutor, just told you. (And no, it is not supported by **most** compilers! There are more than gcc, msvc and clang/llvm.

Comment: There is no way in hell you can just copy/paste together some executable code and expect it to work. For example, the `goto end;` in your code? That's probably a relative jump. You can think for a moment about what that means for your approach to the problem. Go on, we'll wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GCC, I [pinned a variable to a callee saved register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global%20Reg%20Vars) for both x86_64 and aarch64 in to eliminate the relative addressing and relative jump issue.  I also restructured the labels after examining the generated assembly since undesired jumps were being introduced.  I have since compiled it with gcc version 4.8.4 targeting x86_64-linux-gnu and gcc version 6.1.0 targeting aarch64-linux-android, and both produced the intended result of 2.

```
// gcc test.c -O3 && ./a.out; echo $?
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#if defined(__amd64__) || defined(__x86_64__) 
register long i asm ("r15");
#elif defined(__arch64__)
register long i asm ("x16");
#else
#error Unsupported architecture. Supported: x86_64, aarch64
#endif
long main (int argc, char** argv) {
  i = 0;

  void* m = mmap(0,  getpagesize(),
                 PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                 MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
                 -1, 0);

  if (!m) {
    return -1;
  }

  {
    char* x = m;
    memcpy(x, &&L00, &&L01 - &&L00); x += &&L01 - &&L00; // inc
    memcpy(x, &&L00, &&L01 - &&L00); x += &&L01 - &&L00; // inc
    memcpy(x, &&L01, &&L02 - &&L01); x += &&L02 - &&L01; // ret
  }

  goto *m;

  L00: i++;      // inc
  L01: return i; // ret
  L02:;

  return -2;
}
```

**Compile and run with:**

```
gcc test.c -O3 && ./a.out; echo $?
2
```

I will continue to search for a solution that does not involve explicit pinning of a variable to a register.

Comment: Hi, did you find  a solution to your problem? I'm trying to do the same thing for my itnerpreter. Thx!